# Commenting system

Tags: feature-request, comments

A lot of time I asked question in Stack Over.. There is a good answer but something is still not clear. So I reply(comment) to him. But sometime you need to add code also, as he also need to add code which does not support the syntax. Which can be very confusing. Can you add that to the commenting system?

Comment: `You can add code to comments` If you need more put it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the `code in comments` trick works - however, if I've had to make a particularly long comment with code included, then on occasion I've added a "wiki" reply, along the lines of "this is really a comment relating to {whatever}, but I needed more space {now lots of space}".

I don't know if that was good or bad, but it worked, and satisfied my inner compass for not "gaming" anything with an answer that wasn't really an answer.

Answer (score 1):

click the help link under [add comment] to see a summary of the available formatting options.

[image: commenting help]